# Subscribe to REST API with retrofit

Tags: android, real-time-data

I have a list of object that constantly changed at my local server, I need to get notified whenever this list is changed, can I use retrofit to do this?

I user firebase before, but now I'm working on local network using local wifi connection (not connected to internet)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Retrofit` for real-time database monitoring. Use `Firebase Cloud Messaging` (FCM) instead (e.g. send notification from server to device when some change occurs).

There are some other libraries like `MQTT` that you could use, but they all follow same procedure of sending messages from server to device.